# Создание экземпляра класса с динамическим именем

Tags: python-3.x

Можно ли средствами Python создать экземпляр класса с динамическим именем объекта и потом ссылаться на него?

```
name = "hello"
id = 5

obj{name} = LED(id)
```

Нужно создать аналог `objhello = LED(5)`

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Как вы это потом использовать то хотите? Приведите больше примеров.

Comment: Можно, но зачем? Чем не подходит, например, хранение объектов в словаре?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно, но это изврат:

**вариант 1:**

```
name = 'myvar'
value = 5

exec(f'{name} = {value}')

print(myvar)
```

**вариант 2:**

```
vars = locals()
vars[name] = value
```

**вариант 3:**

```
vars = locals()
vars.__setitem__(name, value)
```

**вариант 4:**

```
import sys

setattr(sys.modules[__name__], name, value)
```